# Error in Intreface program in Java: Could not find or load main class interface

Tags: java, interface

This message is shown in an online compiler

Error: You must declared Main class which contains 'main' method, which is entry point of program execution.

```
interface I1{
    void show();
}
class Test implements I1{
    public void show(){
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Test t = new Test();
        t.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: You declared a `Test` class, but not a `Main` class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have main method in a public class

your 'non public class main method' won't work as an entry point of your code.

Answer (score 0):

`class Test implements I1{` to `public class Test implements I1 {`

You need at least one `public static void main` in a `public class ???` (you fill the ???), you can have more, but you can't have none.